# OS selection screen not showing on startup

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, bios

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on a separate hard disk twice. First time I put the boot loader on sdb but it goes straight to Windows 8.1 on startup. So I installed the second time with boot loader on sda however the problem still exists. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Go to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572102/installing-ubuntu-in-another-hard-drive/) question and follow the installation instructions given there. I recommend installing Ubuntu on your **sdb**.

After installation, connect **both** your hard disks first and go into your Ubuntu installed in sdb.

Open a new terminal session ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ) and type the following commands :

`sudo grub-install /dev/sdb`
`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

**Reboot** the system. Windows must have appeared in the grub menu now.

Comment: I cannot get into ubuntu. iI have even tried unplugging sdaA sata cable. And the computer says "No boot device available" this is a dell xps 8500 if it helps any

Comment: I have edited the answer